# Connection refused error in SOAP while sending request to WSDL

Tags: soap, wsdl, request, connection-refused

```
   org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = createCall();
            _call.setUsername("nehalp");
            _call.setPassword("sap@123");
            _call.setOperation(_operations[0]);
            _call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
            _call.setSOAPActionURI("http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1");
            _call.setEncodingStyle(null);
            _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
            _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.PROP_DOMULTIREFS, Boolean.FALSE);
            _call.setSOAPVersion(org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP11_CONSTANTS);
            _call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "Unlock"));


            setRequestHeaders(_call);
            setUsername("nehalp");
            setPassword("sap@123");
            setAttachments(_call);
     try {        java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {unlock_Request_MT});
```

This line throws Exception : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: You really need to show the full stack trace from the Axis call.  Your call be failing for dozens of reason, including username, password, wrong operation, problems in the WSDL, etc.